# how to add class to an anchor which contains specific name

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my html:

```
<div class="names my-3 text-center">
  <a href="#" class="anchor">Susan</a>
  <a href="#" class="anchor">Jack</a>
  <a href="#" class="anchor">Bill</a>
</div> 
<br />
<h5 class="currentname">Jack</h5>
```

One of the anchors that contains the same name as class `currentname` should have class `red` with it.

```
var currentname = $('.currentname').text(); // read currentname in h5
$('.names a').text(name).addClass('red');
```

what i am doing wrong? ( Now they all get red)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `contains`  and add class depends upon that.

```js
var currentname = $('.currentname').text(); // read currentname in h5
$("a.anchor:contains(" + currentname + ")").addClass('red');
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="names my-3 text-center">
  <a href="#" class="anchor">Susan</a>
  <a href="#" class="anchor">Jack</a>
  <a href="#" class="anchor">Bill</a>
</div>
<br />
<h5 class="currentname">Jack</h5>
One of the anchors that contains the same name as class currentname should have class red with it.
```